# When doing game programming, does it matter to iOS, HTML5, or Flash that an image is 72dpi or 300dpi?

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone, dpi

It is somewhat puzzling that when I resize an image to do game programming for iOS, using Preview on Mac OS X Lion, it has an option to choose how many DPI.  I wonder how does it matter if 72dpi is chosen or 300dpi is chosen, as long as it is 100 x 100 pixel, when it is used as game images on the iOS, and HTML5, or Flash, how does it matter at all?

If it doesn't matter at all -- 100 x 100 pixel is 100 x 100 -- then why does Preview on such a new OS (Mac OS X Lion) let us choose what DPI?  This question aims at understanding game programming and usage of the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The DPI (or PPI, pixels per inch) is used as a hint for software and systems that deal with paper: that is, printing and scanning. From the [Wikipedia Dots_per_inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#DPI_or_PPI_in_digital_image_files) article:

> DPI refers to the physical dot density of an image when it is reproduced as a real physical entity, for example printed onto paper, or displayed on a monitor. A digitally stored image has no inherent physical dimensions, measured in inches or centimetres. Some digital file formats record a DPI value, or more commonly a PPI (pixels per inch) value, which is to be used when printing the image. This number lets the printer know the intended size of the image, or in the case of scanned images, the size of the original scanned object.

Because Preview is often used to muck with images that make their way to printers, it makes sense that there's an option to tweak that bit. But it won't have any effect on your gaming applications (unless, of course, they were deliberately written to read that value and behave differently).